# Matlab export_fig: set variable file name as a string and not a number

Tags: matlab

I want to have the option at the beginning of my script to set whether I want to export the figure or not, and to set the name of the exported figure:

```
EXPORT_FIGURE      = 1;
    FIGURE_NAME    = 'some_string';

...

if EXPORT_FIGURE == 1
    export_fig(sprintf('%d', FIGURE_NAME), '-png', '-q101');
end
```

This works fine when `FIGURE_NAME` is a number, but not when I set it as a string. Is there a way around this? If I can use a string, then I can just name the figure at the top of my script.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you used the `'%d'` format specifier which is for numbers. You will need to use `'%s'` for a string.

```
if ischar(FIGURE_NAME)
    filename = sprintf('%s', FIGURE_NAME);
else
    filename = sprintf('%d', FIGURE_NAME);
end

export_fig(filename, '-png', '-q101')
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of sprintf and %d wants to turn the FIGURE_NAME into an integer, this works if FIGURE_NAME is numeric, not if it is a string. The problem is therefore not the export_fig function, but the sprintf function.